# Error : operand type mismatch for 'mov', 'out'

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, inline-assembly

everyone.
I am trying to use the inline assembly technique in c programs.
But, An error : operand type mismatch for 'mov', 'out' occurs when compiling.

My code

```
#define updateCursor(X, Y)({
__asm__ volatile(
       "mov %%al, $0x0f \n\t"
       "mov %%dx, $0x03d4 \n\t"
       "out %%dx, %%al \n\t"

       "mov %%al, %[x] \n\t"         // No-Error
       "mov %%dx, $0x03d5 \n\t"
       "out %%dx, %%al \n\t"
:: (x) "m" (X)
: "al", "dx");
})
```

I do not understand why I get an error on almost every line. (except for the no-error part)

I am very grateful if you help me with what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: In AT*T syntax source operand is first, destination is second. I recommend though creating an out function that takes a value and port and issues the out command. Limit the amount of inline assembly.

Comment: Michael Petch ) Thanks!! :)

Comment: If the first or last instruction in an inline-asm statement is a `mov`, you're usually doing it wrong.  Use constraints properly so the only instruction in the asm statement is `"out %[x], %[port]"`, with a port constraint that allows small integers or `%dx`.